# RailsAdmin dashboard customization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, metrics, rails-admin

I want to display some metrics on my RailsAdmin dashboard
I use custom sql query to do get the data from the DB.

How can I change the dashboard view to show that data?

I can customize `app/views/rails_admin/main/dashboard.html.erb app/views/rails_admin/main/dashboard.html.haml`, but where do I define a query result

`@result = Metric.data`

Thanks

Comment: dpaluy, ever get this figured out?

Comment: @RianRainey I migrated to ActiveAdmin (because of different reasons).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add any number of dashboards if you want

**Rails admin config**

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
config.actions do
    dashboard
    require_relative '../../lib/rails_admin/config/actions/dashboard'

    root :admin_dashboard
    root :teacher_dashboard
    root :director_dashboard
end
```

Redirect to specific dashboard when accessing default one

/lib/rails_admin/config/actions/**dashborad.rb**

```
require 'rails_admin/config/actions'
require 'rails_admin/config/actions/base'

module RailsAdmin
  module Config
    module Actions
      class Dashboard < RailsAdmin::Config::Actions::Base
        RailsAdmin::Config::Actions.register(self)
        register_instance_option :root? do
          true
        end
        register_instance_option :breadcrumb_parent do
        end
        register_instance_option :link_icon do
          'icon-hand-up'
        end
        register_instance_option :controller do
          proc do
            if current_user.instance_of? Teacher
              redirect_to '/admin/teacher_dashboard'
            elsif current_user.instance_of? Director
              redirect_to '/admin/campus_director_dashboard'
            elsif current_user.instance_of? Admin
              redirect_to '/admin/admin_dashboard'
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Exampled of admin dashboard controller

/lib/rails_admin/config/actions/**admin_dashborad.rb**

```
require 'rails_admin/config/actions'
require 'rails_admin/config/actions/base'
module RailsAdmin
  module Config
    module Actions
      class AdminDashboard < RailsAdmin::Config::Actions::Base
        RailsAdmin::Config::Actions.register(self)
        register_instance_option :root? do
          true
        end
        register_instance_option :breadcrumb_parent do
        end
        register_instance_option :link_icon do
          'icon-hand-up'
        end
        register_instance_option :controller do
          proc do
            render action: @action.template_name
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score -2):

Create a **index** method in `app/admin/dashboard.rb` file. Then fetch the results there.
Exp:

```
index do
    # renders app/views/admin/posts/_some_partial.html.erb
    @category = Category.includes(:products).find params[:id]
    render partial: "category_attributes"
  end
```

The partial here for the view of that index method.

Comment: I guess it should be inside Dashboard class. Correct? I tried to use this one https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/blob/master/lib/rails_admin/config/actions/dashboard.rb but it didn't work. Thanks for help

Comment: @dpaluy, In your Application directioy, under the app folder you'll find the admin folder. There is a class named dashboard.rb on that admin folder. You've to write this code on that file.

Comment: there is no such file in RailsAdmin. dashboard.rb file exists in ActiveAdmin

Comment: @dpaluy, Sorry. I guessed you are using the Active admin gem. You're using the rails_admin gem. :(

Comment: I used to work with ActiveAdmin too. But on current project, I have to support RailsAdmin :-)